# Postgres on Rails FATAL: database does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, database-migration

I've reinstalled Postgres (9.2.4) and I'm having trouble getting it set back up with Rails 3.2.11.  I did:

```
brew install postgresql
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

So now I have

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4
$ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

My database.yml file looks like

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: Tyler
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

And when I run `rake db:create:all` then `rake db:migrate` I get the error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
                                    ^
:         SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
          FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
            ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
         WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
           AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
         ORDER BY a.attnum
```

I have tried to clear out everything related to past db, migrations, etc.

I've deleted the schema.rb, seed.rb, and all files in the migrations folder, and anything else I can think of.  But the error referring to "posts" makes me think there is still some old reference to my prior database (which had a table called "posts").

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this error, when trying to completely reinstall/refresh my database?

Comment: This sounds like your migration files are not consistent. Are you sure you are creating `posts` before referencing it?

Comment: I tried putting only the first migration file in the migration folder (which does not reference posts anywhere), and I still get the problem.  I also tried removing ALL migration files, and I still get the message...

Comment: Does `rake db:drop:all` help?

Comment: Are you trying to access the database at the class level in any of your models?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I was having a similar problem.
I checked different websites and tried what they suggested but didn't work.
Then I tried what you suggested.
**`rake db:create:all`** and **`rake db:migrate`** it worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: this wasn't working for me until I adde bundle exec. `bundle exec rake db:create:all`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the databases first. Run rake db:create:all

Also make sure your yml file is set up correctly for postgres.

Answer (score 2):

`db:create:all` and `db:migrate` did not work for me first.
I changed my database name from `development.pg` to `developmentpg` in `myapp/config/database.yml` file:

> database: db/developmentpg

and then **`rake db:create:all`** and **`rake db:migrate`**, it worked for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried running rake db:create:all, which didn't work.
However, running 
    bundle exec rake db:create:all 
worked for me.

Hope this helps!