# Postgres on Rails FATAL: database "my_app_test" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a new rails environment I'm setting up and I'm having some issues with postgres connecting to the database when running RSPEC tests.

My environment is Ruby 2.2.4p230, Rails 3.2.22, Postgresql 9.4.5

My database.yml file looks like:

```
  test:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: myapp_com_test
    min_messages: WARNING
    pool: 5
    username: 
    password:
```

I can run `rake db:migrate` and not receive any errors.

I can also run `rails c test` and the console seems to launch and shows me:

```
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
Loading test environment (Rails 3.2.22)
[1] pry(main)>
```

But when I run something like `rake db:test:prepare` it looks like it runs fine in that terminal window, but I receive a `FATAL:  database "myapp_com_test" does not exist` in the server window.

Along the same lines, when I run `rake spec` I receive the same `FATAL:  database "myapp_com_test" does not exist` in the server window along with this error

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
   (0.6ms)  SELECT version FROM schema_migrations ORDER BY version
   (126.3ms)  DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "myapp_com_test"
   (236.5ms)  CREATE DATABASE "myapp_com_test" ENCODING = 'unicode'
/Users/ryanfitch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/account_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/artists_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/contact_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/exclusivities_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/help_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/legal_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/line_items_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/mixtapes_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/newsletter_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/order_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/originals_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/stations_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/story_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/tracks_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb ./spec/decorators/exclusivities_decorator_spec.rb ./spec/decorators/station_decorator_spec.rb ./spec/features/user_creates_account_spec.rb ./spec/features/user_places_click_order_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/exclusivities_helper_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/stations_helper_spec.rb ./spec/models/address_spec.rb ./spec/models/artist_spec.rb ./spec/models/billing_information_spec.rb ./spec/models/exclusivity_spec.rb ./spec/models/license_spec.rb ./spec/models/line_item_spec.rb ./spec/models/mixtape_download_spec.rb ./spec/models/mixtape_spec.rb ./spec/models/order_spec.rb ./spec/models/outbox_spec.rb ./spec/models/promo_code_spec.rb ./spec/models/side_spec.rb ./spec/models/station_spec.rb ./spec/models/track_rank_spec.rb ./spec/models/track_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb ./spec/models/vendor_spec.rb ./spec/routing/artists_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/contact_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/help_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/home_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/legal_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/mixtapes_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/originals_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/story_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/tracks_routing_spec.rb ./spec/views/stations/play.html.erb_spec.rb
invalid option: --no-fail-fast

Please use --help for a listing of valid options
/Users/ryanfitch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/account_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/artists_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/contact_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/exclusivities_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/help_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/legal_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/line_items_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/mixtapes_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/newsletter_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/order_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/originals_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/stations_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/story_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/tracks_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb ./spec/decorators/exclusivities_decorator_spec.rb ./spec/decorators/station_decorator_spec.rb ./spec/features/user_creates_account_spec.rb ./spec/features/user_places_click_order_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/exclusivities_helper_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/stations_helper_spec.rb ./spec/models/address_spec.rb ./spec/models/artist_spec.rb ./spec/models/billing_information_spec.rb ./spec/models/exclusivity_spec.rb ./spec/models/license_spec.rb ./spec/models/line_item_spec.rb ./spec/models/mixtape_download_spec.rb ./spec/models/mixtape_spec.rb ./spec/models/order_spec.rb ./spec/models/outbox_spec.rb ./spec/models/promo_code_spec.rb ./spec/models/side_spec.rb ./spec/models/station_spec.rb ./spec/models/track_rank_spec.rb ./spec/models/track_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb ./spec/models/vendor_spec.rb ./spec/routing/artists_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/contact_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/help_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/home_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/legal_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/mixtapes_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/originals_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/story_routing_spec.rb ./spec/routing/tracks_routing_spec.rb ./spec/views/stations/play.html.erb_spec.rb failed
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

---

EDIT:
I can run `rails db test` and it opens up the database console and shows me the schema so the test database and dev database are there and seem to be working - but Postgres still doesn't seem to find it when I run `rake spec` for some reason.

Comment: are you sure it's called `myapp_com_test` and not `my_app_test` like the title of your question indicates ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Postgres on Rails FATAL: database does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933522/postgres-on-rails-fatal-database-does-not-exist)

Try a `rake db:create:all` and then a `rake db:migrate`

Comment: rake db:create:all just tells me that the databases are already there, and rake db:migrate still runs fine.