# rake aborted! ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL: database "appname_development" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

A rails 5.2.3 (ruby 2.5.1p57) app worked perfectly locally.

I ran `rake db:drop` to remove it, then `rake db:reset` to reset, migrate and seed, and it did so perfectly.

Then, for unrelated reasons, I dropped it again in the same way but when I recreated it with `rake db:reset` I got the following error

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "appname_development" does not exist
```

I have tried 
`rake db:create:all` as set out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933522/postgres-on-rails-fatal-database-does-not-exist)
also
`bundle exec rake db:create` as set out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean) and in most other answers

It appears the symptom is common, but the main antedotes don't seem to help in my case. It's also *really* odd that I ran the same thing moments earlier and it worked, and seemingly nothing had changed in between

Comment: What is output when you run `rake db:create` ?

Comment: try deleting your schema file then run `rails db:create`

Comment: @Vishal your comment made me scrutinize the output more closely. It says `/config/routes.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'`. I checked the routes. I had some code in there that should have been commented out. Thanks so much